# How to use GTEST/GMOCK to check if member function of a class has been called?

Tags: c++, googletest

I have in production a class, simplified as below:

```
class MyClass{
  public:
    MyClass(std::string input){//}
    void myFunc(){
       // do something
    } 
};
```

I have a piece of code (`otherCode.cpp`) that instantiates an object of `MyClass`:

```
//in the middle of otherCode.cpp
auto myObj = MyClass("abc");
myObj.myFunc();
//keeps going and runs other code
```

In my test, I want to ensure that `myFunc()` is actually run. But I do not want to mock `myFunc()` or `MyClass`. That is, I actually want the real code  to execute with respect to `MyClass` and `myFunc()`.

All I want to verify is that `myFunc()` was called and let the code run as is in my test.

How can I do that with gtest/gmock?

Comment: It's impossible w/o a modification of myFunc.

Comment: You should rethink your requirements or test design. If you want to test othercode, why do you require that the real code is called? A mocked method with the correct return values should be sufficient.

Comment: ? lets say othercode is designed to return the value 5.0, and in doing so , it needs the results of `myObj.myFunc()`. So I simply want to make sure the entire otherCode.cpp actually returns 5.0, and in doing so, it also calls `myObj.myFunc()`.